# How can I use rvest to parse html fragments when some may not be html?

Tags: r, rvest

My data consists of a list of strings containing repro steps for bugs.  These are usually encoded as html, but occasionally are just raw text and occasionally are empty (NA).  I need the text sans html.  I am trying to accomplish this with rvest but I am running into issues.

I have this function which will parse a line of html and return a string:

```
library(rvest)
tf <- function(frag) {read_html(frag) %>% html_nodes("p") %>% html_text() %>% paste0(collapse = " ")}
```

This works on proper html:

```
foo <- c("<p>captain <p>tightpants", "<p>malcolm <p>reynolds")
lapply(foo, tf)
```

works as expected.  I get two strings back.

If I have NAs though, it tries to load a file named "NA":

```
foo <- c("<p>captain <p>tightpants", "<p>malcolm <p>reynolds", NA)
lapply(foo, tf)
```

Likewise, if I have a string that is not html, it also tries to load a file:

```
foo <- c("<p>captain <p>tightpants", "<p>malcolm <p>reynolds", "something else")
lapply(foo, tf)
```

Is there a way to get rvest to always assume the string is html?  Is there a different package I should be using?

Comment: The XML library is much less convenient, but does have an asText parameter which will overcome this issue.  Is there anything like that in rvest?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps pass the vector elements through `htmltidy::tidy_html()` first so you always have HTML and use a more liberal XPath selector to get all the text (and clean it up before returning it):

```
library(rvest)
library(htmltidy)

tf <- function(frag) {

  tidy_html(frag) %>%   
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes(xpath="//*[not(self::script)]/text()") %>% 
    html_text() %>% 
    paste0(collapse = " ") %>% 
    gsub("\\n", "", .) %>% 
    gsub("\ +", " ", .) %>% 
    trimws()

}

foo <- c("<p>captain <p>tightpants", "<p>malcolm <p>reynolds", "something else")
lapply(foo, tf)
## [[1]]
## [1] "captain tightpants"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "malcolm reynolds"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "something else"
```

If you're sure the text is "clean" (i.e. no `<script>` tags) then you can make the selector `"//*/text()"`.

Though, might I also suggest:

```
library(purrr)

map_chr(foo, tf)
## [1] "captain tightpants" "malcolm reynolds"   "something else"
```

As it'll return a character vector vs a list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!  I will try them out.